# Xamarin Forms - Shiny.AndroidShinyHost not available

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Shiny for xamarin to schedule background jobs.

I am trying to call my startup class from my mainApplication class but AndroidShinyHost is not available. My Target is Android 10.

I used the following sample
https://github.com/shinyorg/samples/tree/main/Jobs

MainApplication.CS

```
using System;
using Shiny;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace Inventory.Droid
{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : Application
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            Shiny.AndroidShinyHost.Init(this, new Startup()); //Not available
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `AndroidShinyHost` anywhere in the code that you linked to

Comment: Sample.Android -- > MainApplication.cs

Comment: I looked at that.  There are two lines of code and neither of them reference `AndroidShinyHost`.  A search of the repo returns 0 hits

Comment: It was changed yesterday.

Comment: I have changes it to this.ShinyOnCreate(new Startup()); but does not exist aswell. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: have you downloaded the sample and tried it?  Are you sure you have the correct nuget installed?  Do you have the correct using statements?

Comment: I have installed the correct nuget packages and am using correct using statements. I ran the sample project. The only difference is the target version is 12

Comment: Did you ding the solution?

Comment: Yes find the shiny version that matches your Android build target